# Querying via a form with value from textbox as criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

The situation: metadata about biological specimens are collected in an Access table. 
The specimens come from human patients and patient data are collected in a separate table.
 To limit the amount of private health information we have hanging around, the patient database must be updated with new patients only when we actually receive samples from them.

So that the data entry workers know when they need to update the patient table, I want a button in the specimen data entry form that will pass an entered patient id value as criteria to a query.

The query looks like this right now:

```
SELECT Patients.[Patient id]
FROM Patients
WHERE (((Patients.[Patient id])=[Forms]![Specimen entry]![patient id]));
```

but it never has results, even when I run it from records that I know correspond to patients in the patient table. 
How do I fix this?

Suggestions about what to call this situation so that I can make better searches about it would also be appreciated. I'm an Access novice.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks correct, but make sure the WHERE clause is comparing numbers to numbers or strings to strings (not a number to a string).  Also confirm that the form and textbox names are correct.  A quick test using your query worked for me.

Depending on how you plan to present the information, you can also dynamically create the query in VBA and then pass the information to the form.

For searching, I'd recommend some combination of access, dynamic, query, and vba.

**alternative option**

If you're only looking to see if a single patient exists in the table, it may be simpler to use the dlookup function:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[Patient ID]", "Patients", "[Patient ID]='" & Me.Patient_ID & "'")) Then MsgBox "does not exist"
```

This will check to see if the patient exists (return a number) or does not exist (returns NULL).

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937